# Trouble with basic F# syntax for applying a partially applied function to a list

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm a raw beginner with F#, so forgive me if this question is stupid or has already been asked in a way I don't even understand yet, but I've read over my basics a few times now, and I'm trying to do something that looks almost identical to examples that work, only it doesn't. I'm trying to create a function to determine the number of possible combinations (unordered) of a set with n members, for subsets sized 1 .. n.

```
let factorial n = [1..n] |> List.reduce (*) 
printfn "3! = %d" (factorial 4) // Works fine

let combinations m n = (factorial m / (factorial (m - n ) * factorial n))
printfn "%d" (combinations 6 4) // Also works fine

let cn n = [1..5] |> List.map (combinations 6)
cn 5 |> List.sum |> printfn "%d" // Works as well, we're almost where i want to be...

let cn' n = [1..n] |> List.map (combinations n)
cn' 6 |> List.sum |> printfn "%d" // System.ArgumentException: The input list was empty.
```

How are these functions different? Is it because I'm using the parameter `n` as part of a range specification? Or as a "baked in" argument in a partially applied function? I can see that the first function `cn`has the signature `cn : n:'a -> int list`, whereas `cn'` has the signature `cn' : n:int -> int list`. Unfortunately I don't know what this means yet, but why does substituting literals with a variable change the signature like this? Is this the most sensible way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually hiding in your definitions, note that in `cn` you have 
`1..5` and `combinations 6`.

You probably want `cn'` to have `1..(n-1)` to match.

Comment: You're right, that fixed it, but opened a new can of worms - looks like the problem was that `combinations 6 6` returns null. When I do it on paper/by hand, `combinations 6 6` should equal 1. What's F# doing differently?

Comment: @Toadfish - what is `[1..0]` - and in particular `[1..0] |> List.reduce (*)`?

Comment: right no i get it now I was literally just about to delete my comment haha. I should just make a case to handle the (totally trivial) case of when the 'subset' size = the set size

Comment: @Toadfish - To avoid having to write special-case code for the "subset size = set size" case, simply replace your `List.reduce (*)` with `List.fold (*) 1`. The `fold` function acts just like `reduce`, except that with `fold` you supply the initial value, so it can handle empty lists.

Comment: In the end I just added a case to the factorial so it could handle 0 itself